# MySQL Before Update Trigger Skipped Sometimes

Tags: mysql, triggers

Due to the lack of computed columns on MySQL, I've decided to use a before update trigger to work around it. Very often I need to perform SELECTs based on the sum of three columns. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (A+B+C) > 0
```

Because of that, I've created a 4th column and a before update trigger:

```
SET new.D = new.A + new.B + new.C;
```

Now I can make:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE D > 0
```

But every once in a while, I find records that are wrongly computed. No other piece of code I have sets the value for the 4th column, besides the trigger. I have no idea of what might be going on. Any guesses?

Thank you.

Comment: what about inserts? update triggers don't catch inserts, and you'd be leaving your `D` field unchanged.

Comment: Well, that gave me an idea. Now that you've mentioned it, I've remembered that I have a routine for duplicating records. It was setting to zero the first three columns, but not the fourth one. I guess that was it. I've fixed my code and will keep an eye on it. Thank you very much!